# Why isn't Lucy always seen when time travelling?

Tags: time-travel, lucy

Question about time travel in the movie *Lucy*.

When she is travelling back in time she can be seen by the:

- Lucy ape
- the dinosaur is going after her
- the native Americans

But people don't notice here when she is in place in New York.

Is there a reason why she can be seen by some and not by some one else?

Comment: Why do you believe the New Yorkers didn't see her?

Comment: Everyone seems to be involved in their own world, attached to  their phones and other gadgets, they haven't looked up from their own world to notice that Lucy has appeared. This is a pretty blatant commentary on the modern person and the small insulated bubble we live in.

Comment: Yes this is true about the modern New York , but what about the New York from 1900 (1:50)

Comment: even in the modern New York - I should think someone in a chair suddenly appearing in Time Square would get some attention... I think the only answer for this would be "because she didn't want to be seen"...